# How to keep processes running after ending ssh session when systemd kills processes after user logs out?

Tags: ssh, systemd, process

I've tried many highly voted answers on stack exchange suggesting nohup, disown, command &, and (command &) and they did not work for me on Ubuntu server 20.04.  I found this answer why they don't work since 2016, due to a systemd default change in how it treats user processes after user logout - [Details](https://serverfault.com/questions/463366/does-getting-disconnected-from-an-ssh-session-kill-your-programs/463375#463375)

There seems to be  way with systemd (the elephant in the room) - see this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634380/506835)
But that requires creating systemd services and managing through systemctl, etc.

Is there a way to configure systemd to change the behavior?

I've found this answer for Oracle Linux: [Configure Systemd to Enable User Processes to Continue to Run After Logout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/obe-systemd-linger/#before-you-begin)

Will this work with Ubuntu?  I could see problems if many users create many processes and do not manage them.  This is for a system with only a few users and few processes.

Comment: Looking at the link you posted about configuring systemd to enable the processes to continue, I cannot see any reason why it would not work.  All files required are there in Ubuntu 20.04.  Unfortunately, I don't have Ubuntu Server installed on any of my systems so I cannot verify for the Server part, but I would assume that it is not much different as far as systemd goes.